# "I found no \citation commands", while there is the .bib reference in the document

Tags: biblatex

Consider the following code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,usenames,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee, maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
    %\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\cite{someReferenceInBiblioFile}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> Process started
>
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 21.1) The top-level auxiliary
> file: test.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file
> test.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux I
> found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux (There were 3
> error messages)
>
> Process exited with error(s)

What is wrong here? Am I not using properly the package?

Comment: Your document is using biblatex, so use biber not bibtex to process the bib file

Comment: biber is the default but you are also specifying explicitly: `backend=biber`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not sure to understand what you mean. Do you mean that the code written is correct but it is in the parameters of my tex editor that I should ask to change the compilation method?

Comment: yes you are running pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, but need pdflatex, biber, pdflatex

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how you can configure your editor to run Biber (instead of BibTeX). https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains what Biber (and BibTeX) do and why you need to run them in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!